# Sliding Tab jumping about jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive built a little jquery sliding div on my website that when you hover over the tab, the div slides in from the right, and on the mouse leave event, the div slides back out of view. The problem im having however is if you very quickly move your mouse over the tab then off, then over and keep repeating this the div slides in and out repeatedly; Is there anyway I can stop this?

Thanks

```
$('.pillars-wrapper').mouseenter(function() {
$('.handle').fadeOut();
    $('.tab-wrapper').animate({
    right: '+=175'
})
});

$('.pillars-wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
$('.tab-wrapper').animate({    
    right: '-=175'
});
$('.handle').fadeIn()
});
```

Heres a fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/FXAcP/

Comment: So, it should only fire once per complete animation?

Comment: yeah, so if you mouse over and leave over and leave repeatedly, at the minute then it keeps opening and closing, I want it to sort of 'understand' the users intent and not keep animating

Comment: set a boolean to say that animation is currently underway. `if(started) return; started = true;` set to false again on completion of animation using callback. `started` must of course be a variable in the window scope, not the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wVMu6/11/

Sorry man, for your old post - I replied 2 mins back but realized its deleted,

Also please note that you have `.tab-wrapper` as a main container, I thought I will mention if you will get some random css issue.

Hope this helps, cheers! B-)

**code**

```
 $('.pillars-wrapper').mouseenter(function() {
     $('.handle').fadeOut().stop();
    $('.tab-wrapper').animate({
        right: '+=175px'
    }, "slow").stop(true,true);

}).mouseleave(function() {

    $('.tab-wrapper').animate({
        right: '-=175px'
    }, "slow").stop(true,true);
    $('.handle').fadeIn().stop();

});​
```

Comment: This seems to allow the div to crawl across the page @Tats_innit

Comment: @Liam this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/wVMu6/11/ ; look into `slideToggle` man that is what you need :) simple toggle, this will not go out of page, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how i solved this problem:

```
$("#menu-balticpoint li").mouseover(function() {

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var width = $("#"+id+" a").width();
                $("#"+id+" ul li a").css("width", width+"px");
                $("#"+id+" ul").slideDown('fast').show();
        $(this).hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $("#"+id+" ul").fadeOut('slow').hide().stop(true, true); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .clearQueue().

For example, instead of

```
$('.tab-wrapper').animate({
```

do

```
 $('.tab-wrapper').clearQueue().animate({
```

You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the time to make appropriate movement of animation.

For example, to lower the speed of sliding, use 'slow' parameter in animate.

```
$('.tab-wrapper').animate({
      right: '-=175'
  },'slow');
```

You may need to read [animation docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) on jquery here.